# Can we create an PDS inside an PDS

Tags: mainframe

I am new to mainframes and i just knew that i can create an PDS inside an PDS since we are specifying directory blocks while ceating. But while creating a member it by default creating an PS. Is it possible to create an PDS inside an PDS? If yes please tell me with details. Thank you

Comment: You can use IEBGENER and IEBUPDTE to pack and unpack datasets.  So you can do this, but the PDS must be flatened out into a packed form and then stored within the outer PDS.  This is pretty much the same as using TSO XMIT to convert the PDS to a flat file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  There really are no details to add, a PDS is not a directory and you cannot create subdirectories inside of it.

Comment: Ok.Thank you. Then members in PDS and PS are same?

Comment: A PS (Physical Sequential) dataset isn't a PDS (Partitioned Dataset).  The former doesn't have members.

Comment: No no my question is: I've created a member in PDS named file1, and another ps with name file2. Now are these both(file1 and file2) same

Comment: Can you please clarify? Do you have a PDS with two members, file1 and file2?

Comment: FILE1 - It is a member is a PDS,   FILE2 - It is PS which is not in any PDS.

Comment: @Pramod, I believe that zarchasmpgmr's answer below is in response to your question.  He is saying that a PS and a PDS member are essentially the same.

Answer (score 11):

Think of a PDS as a PO (DSORG) file where the members are equivalent to PS (DSORG) files.

Unlike putting a ZIP file inside a ZIP file, you cannot put a PDS inside a PDS member. In the IBM world, that logically does not make sense.

Answer (score 2):

While I agree with the other answers given I feel I must point out that you can store another PDS in inside of a PDS in a non-direct sort of way.

You can use TSO XMIT to store a PDS as a member inside of another PDS.

XMIT will pack the PDS into NETDATA format as 80 byte records which can be stored inside of another PDS.

If you then want to change, view or delete a member in the PDS that was converted by XMIT, you'll have to restored the XMITed PDS to its original format by way of the TSO RECEIVE command which reverses the whole process.  Then make whatever changes you like to the members in that PDS.